# Problem with building c++ project with opencv and dlib libraries via cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, makefile, cygwin

I use c++ project with opencv and dlib libraries. I have CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)

project(project1)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(dlib
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
    GIT_TAG        v19.18
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(dlib)

add_executable(project1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(project1 ${OpenCV_LIBS} dlib::dlib)
target_compile_options(project1 PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${MY_RELEASE_OPTIONS}>")
```

I write in cygwin cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles". I use "Unix Makefiles" to create makefile that use to command "make". After this I write make, but as a result I get error:

```
collect2: error: ld execution ended with return code 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/project1.dir/build.make:123: project1.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:115: CMakeFiles/project1.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

What I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: Are there more details to the error message on the preceding lines?

Comment: To expand on Alan's message: the output you've provided aren't actually the error messages, that's why they have no actual information in them.  They're just messages that are printed AFTER the errors, saying "something failed".  You have to go look earlier in the output to find the actual messages.  Whenever you're dealing with compiling and linking programs, it's almost invariably the case that the **FIRST** error messages are the most interesting/useful, and the last messages are the least interesting/useful.